# MVC Controller Action called from PartialView in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my _Layout.cshtml I want to include a dropdown list in the site header. I'm not positive of the best way to do this, but I've tried to code it using a PartialView. It seems to be working, but when the form is submitted the page loads with only the dropdownlist.

**ViewModel:**

```
namespace XXXX_Web_App.Models
{
    public class LanguageListPartial
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LanguageList()
{
    ViewBag.LanguageList = GetLanguageList();

    return PartialView("_LanguageListPartial");
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> LanguageList(string language)
{
    // Save selection to cookie
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
    cookie["Language"] = language;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    // Save selection to user profile
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        String userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        user.Language = language;
        await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    }

    ViewBag.LanguageList = GetLanguageList();

    return PartialView("_LanguageListPartial");
}

public List<SelectListItem> GetLanguageList()
{
    List<SelectListItem> languages = new List<SelectListItem>();
    languages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "English", Value = "en-US" });
    languages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Fran&#231;ais", Value = "fr-CA" });
    languages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Portugu&#234;s", Value = "pt-BR" });
    languages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Espa&#241;ol", Value = "es-MX" });
    return languages;
}
```

**Partial View:**

```
@model XXXX_Web_App.Models.LanguageListPartial

@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Language,
    new SelectList(ViewBag.LanguageList, "Value", "Text"), 
    new { @class = "form-control toggle", onchange = "this.form.submit();"
})
```

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
@using Westwind.Globalization;
@using Westwind.Globalization.Resources;

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") 
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryUI")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div style="">

    <div class="header container">

         ... nav menu ...

    </div>

    <form action="/Account/LanguageList" method="post" >
        @{Html.RenderAction("LanguageList", "Account");}
    </form>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="container">
        <hr />
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
    </footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The desired logic is:

**Every site/page visit**

- Anonymous user - load selection from cookie. Default to English. (not done yet)
- Authenticated user - load selection from user profile (not done yet)

**On selection**

- Anonymous user - save selection to cookie
- Authenticated user - save selection to cookie and update user profile

Like I said, this seems to be working except that when a selection is made the Controller action gets called and when the page reloads the only thing on the page is the dropdown list.

How do I return the View in this situation?

One other question, I would like the text in the dropdown list items to include the culture specific decorations, but they are displaying literally like `Fran&#231;ais` instead. I don't see how I can use `Html.Encode()` in this situation. It's probably being caused by the way I am adding the items in `GetLanguageList()`. How do I avoid this?

**EDIT**

To clarify, my excerpt from _Layout.cshtml above is just that - an excerpt. My _Layout.cshtml contains what you might expect of it - a header with logo and subtitle, navigation menu, and RenderBody() code. The page displays properly on the Partial View's GET Controller Action, but when I make a selection from the dropdown list the POST Controller Action only the dropdown list is displayed on the page - nothing else. _Layout.cshtml is gone and so are the contents of whatever page I am on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form the /Account/LanguageList action is called. It returns with only a partial view:

```
return PartialView("_LanguageListPartial");
```

When you return just this, your _layout file is not called.

So what you want is to return another view. Unless you specify it, all your views will contain your _layout.cshtml file. And that already contains the partial view.

So create a new view and return that when you post to the form.

Comment: I am new to MVC and don't understand how to create a view that contains both. Is this done in the controller action? I have been reading article after article about Partial views. I've learned a lot about MVC, but am stuck on Partial Views right now.

Comment: Well, your _layout file does contain both today. But your _layout file  is a template where you can insert content from other view files. Create a new default MVC application from Visual Studio and you can see an example of how it all fits together.

Comment: So typically you will have a layout file with your header information, perhaps navigation and where your main content will go you will see @RenderBody(). That's where the content from other view files will go.

Comment: Yes Michael, _Layout.cshtml exists and is where I am making the `@{Html.RenderAction("LanguageList", "Account");}` call. I'm not understanding what you are saying. Create another layout just because I want a Partial View within _Layout.cshtml? I'm sorry, I'm just not understanding your direction, though I appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: Maybe you are interpreting my excerpt in _Layout.cshtml above as being the entire file? My _Layout.html has a header, nav menu, RenderBody() and a footer. It works well. But RenderAction() caused only the dropdown list to be displayed.

Comment: Michael, I updated my question and included more of _Layout.cshtml. I understand why you were pointing me the way you were. No, there is a lot more to my layout than just a `<form>` tag enclosing an `Html.RenderAction()`. Please see my EDIT.

Comment: No. I didn't think it was the entire file. But in your project you have several controllers and views. And when you submit the form you need to return something else than just a partial view. You need a "full view". That "full view" will use _layout.cshtml which contains your partial.

Comment: You could of course also use ajax to submit that form. And instead of returning a view, return a json result.

Comment: I've seen some examples on doing it with Ajax, but I'm trying to learn MVC. There must be a way... In the POST Controller Action for the partial view I've tried `return view()`, `return view("_Layout")`, `return PartialView("_Layout")`, and `return PartialView("_LanguageListPartial")`. They all have their own errors. Ajax doesn't help in this situation because the dropdown causes the page to be refreshed into a different language. It has to reload.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56178/discussion-between-michael-furstenberg-and-rwkiii).

Comment: Michael, your suggestion in chat worked. I changed the `return` to `return RedirectToLocal(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);` and that reloads the current page and accomplishes exactly what I am needing. Thank you for your suggestions.